# Is it possible to have geofencing in PWA?

Tags: next.js, progressive-web-apps, geofencing

I have just developed my first Nextjs web app. And I would like to make PWA out of it.

I have this feature that user should get notificaiton when it enters particular area on the map(even if the app is not being used at the moment). Is it possible to do such a thing with PWA?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.